# Which password is required to unlock my accounts?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, keystore, recovery, password

What password is my geth 1.3.5 ethereum wallet asking for when I try to send a transaction? I am having trouble figuring this out since I don't remember a wallet password on setup.

Answer (score 4):

this is the password you got asked to enter twice when you created your account with `geth account new`

see the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#creating-an-account), you entered this password twice :

```
$ geth account new
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase:
Repeat Passphrase:
Address: {168bc315a2ee09042d83d7c5811b533620531f67}
```